# Can I pass a 3D array declared as double ***array by using &array[0][0][0]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to implement the routines for a 3D Fourier Transform from *Numerical Recipes in C*. 
They have the functions

```
void rlft3(double ***data, double **speq, unsigned long nn1, unsigned long nn2, unsigned long nn3, int isign);
void fourn(double data[], unsigned long nn[], int ndim, int isign);
```

(They originally had `float`, which I changed to `double`.)

They call `fourn()` from `rlft3()` like so:

```
fourn(&data[1][1][1]-1,nn,3,isign);
```

which I modified to

```
fourn(&data[0][0][0],nn,3,isign);
```

When I do this, I get only the first column -- in other words, one dimension-- of my matrix `data` passed, instead of the whole thing. This vaguely makes sense to me, since (as I understand the code `&data[i][j][k]`) I passed only a 'single' pointer to something that is actually referenced by a triple pointer -- but is it *supposed* to work as they wrote it? If so, how does the compiler know where the other dimensions are?

I'm having trouble understanding why my call didn't work properly, because I don't quite understand what the strategy here is in first place.

Comment: NR for C/C++ (at least the first versions) had the horrible idea to use FORTRAN-style 1-based indexing *in C*. They included their own memory allocation routines for multi-dimensional arrays (matrices) to allow for such an offset, so that such arrays could be indexed as e.g. `matrix[1][1]` referring to the very first element, and `matrix[n][n]` referring to the last element for an n by n matrix.

Comment: [cont.] I mention this, because if you are going to change that indexing scheme (rightfully so), you'll end up into various issues and 1-off errors elsewhere. If you can, re-implement things *completely* yourself. Use only the math from the books, not their code.

Comment: It may be helpful if you mention which version of NR you actually use, so people may be able to look up the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm 99% sure I figured out what the problem was:

Although the NR (and indeed, it's the 1988 second edition that is complete with FORTRAN-style indexing) function `rlft3()` is written to accept `double ***data` as an argument,  it is designed so that this triple pointer must be a pointer that was declared separately and then made to reference/point at an array that *already existed* and *was declared statically*. What I had done was send `rlft3()` a matrix `***data` from a wrapper function where that triple pointer had had memory dynamically allocated to it directly. Therefore, the memory was not contiguous and could not be found all from one pointer passed using the & operator, as I think it would be if it pointed to a statically allocated array.